# How to vibrate Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE device?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, sketch, adafruit

I have 11 Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit LE devices. I want to vibrate my devices using a signal through an app. Is there any signal (Code from app like 0x56-NeoPixel checking, 0x43-clear color) or any sketch? Please provide me.

Comment: I can't find any device called "adafeuit feature 32u bluefeature le". Did you mean "Adafruit Feather 32u4 Bluefruit"?

Comment: If it is that Feather device how do you expect it to "vibrate"? What have you added to it that can vibrate?

Comment: If you can't even spell the board name correctly you have no hope of success with Arduino. Either start using your brain or give up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Adafruit Feather you are talking about is a small format Arduino compatible with BlueTooth Low Energy, USB and battery connector. It doesn't have any way to vibrate without adding external hardware.

[image: Adafruit Feather]

Now, having Bluetooth in the package means that it can comunicate with an Android Phone, and can send/receive commands, post results, anything you need.

We don't provide sketchs for particular projects. You must learn how to program Arduino and Android. Follow the examples and tutorials widely available in the Web.

Comment: Altermo - Thanks for your feedback, And Yes i added external hardware for vibrate and  i found sketch code for vibrate my device.